# Bootstrap navbar dropdown links don't work in Safari

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, safari, mobile-safari

Simply put: has anyone managed to get Bootstrap dropdown nav links to work in Safari (any user agent)? I have looked through at least five similar threads, but none of the standard fixes work in my case.

Everything is fine in Chrome/Firefox, but nothing happens when the links are clicked in Safari (both Desktop and mobile). I'm using Meteor.

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">    
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{selectedItem}}<span class="caret"></span></a>

     <ul id="selectItem" class="dropdown-menu nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a id="abc" href="#">ABC</a></li>
          <li><a id="def" href="#">DEF</a></li>
          <li><a id="ghi" href="#">GHI</a></li>                                                                 
     </ul>
 </li>
```

JS:

```
Template.navigation.events({
  'click #selectItem': function(){
    var selectedItem = document.activeElement.getAttribute("id");
    Session.set('selectedItem', selectedItem);
  }
});
```

Comment: Add a really high z index perhaps?

Comment: Thanks, I tried this. Safari still recognizes that the click happened - it just doesn't register the activeElement value (logs it as null).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I have figured out a workaround. This works in all browsers:

```
Template.navigation.events({
  'click #selectedItem': function(e){
    var selectedItem = e.target.id;
    Session.set('selectedItem', selectedItem);
  }
});
```